# After drupal 6> 7 upgrade attached pdf links not visible

Tags: 7, entities

After upgrade fromn 6 > 7  attachment information is not visible in nodes.  Data exists in dbase.  What is best approach to re-connecting pdf, mp3 and other attachments to specific nodes. (2000 or so)

Comment: what error messages did you receive in the `site-upgrade` command ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CCK migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck) module to migrate (import) the D6 fields to D7 . CCK migrate module is the part of CCK module in drupal 7.

[Here is the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1144136) how to do it.